# Newer version Artifactory is having problems with Jenkins Artifactory plugin

Tags: jenkins, certificate, ssl-certificate, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I have two Artifactory servers, one is a version 3.4.1 and the other is 6.0.2
The Jenkins is configured to push to two Artifactories with different Ids as shown below [image]
The old Artifactory is working fine and Jenkins is able to connect to it but, the new Artifactory is throwing an exception and is not able to connect to it.

Here is an excerpt from the log:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project JavaApplications: Could not resolve dependencies for project JavaApplications:JavaApplications:jar:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sf.jt400:jt400-full:jar:5.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.sf.jt400:jt400-full:jar:5.4: Could not transfer artifact net.sf.jt400:jt400-full:pom:5.4 from/to central (http://artifactory/artifactory/libs-release): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

Clearly, something to do with the certificates? please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Jenkis `*.crt` file into `cacerts`. There is simple guild on Artifactory [page](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error/).